# $100 divided by 3: What happens to the $0.01?

Tags: banking, calculation

Frustrated with the current bookkeeping app I use, I've decided to start making my own with the intent to publish it. While I was on it, one thing that was immediately apparent is what happens to those "leftover" amounts when, say, $10 is divided by 3. It happens when a transaction gets split.

I did some research on the matter, but unfortunately haven't found any other answer aside from "do what you're accustomed to doing" or simply following the usual rounding rules (0.016 = 0.02; 0.034 = 0.03).

Are there any laws or regulations that specifically say what happens to those leftover amounts (or what they're even called)?

They're pretty small, but over tens of thousands of transactions, those $0.01 add up.

If specific context is needed, I'm from the Philippines

**Edit:** I'm asking about how calculations are done for finance and the considerations needed (legal or whatnot, if any), and *not* how to program it.

Comment: In what context would you be dividing amounts in a bookkeeping application?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a software product that the OP is wanting to develop, perhaps for sale, and not about an issue of _personal finance_.

Comment: @DilipSarwate This is a question about personal accounting, which is on-topic. The OP’s reason for asking is irrelevant.

Comment: @DilipSarwate I'm asking about how calculations are done for finance and the considerations needed (legal or whatnot, if any), and *not* how to program it. I reckoned this SE would be the appropriate place to ask. The answer sounds like a programming answer though, but it gave a really important insight (offload that decision to the user).

Comment: You need to watch the movie "Office Space" :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You get to decide. If you want $100 to be split as $33.33, $33.33, $33.34, or $30, $30, $40, or whatever, it's your choice.

The bookkeeping app isn't (and shouldn't be) responsible for how you decide to split your invoices.

I wouldn't want my software to tell me that the extra cent *must* go to the third person, or that I *must* split a 3-item account as evenly as possible. I might actually want the $100 split as $10, $20, $70 because that's what the individual items cost. The accounting package wouldn't know, and so it shouldn't impose any rules about how entries are split.

Comment: I think there are actual accounting rules about how this works.

Comment: +1 For every personal accounting software program I've used, when you split a transaction you must manually enter how much goes to each split.  It does not simply split the transaction evenly, as that is rarely what you want anyway.  As a result, the software does not need to impose any rounding rules.

Comment: @DJClayworth Exactly. I'm looking to find out about it if there are any.